# How to add different logo when i scroll down?

Tags: javascript, css

I have made a page which has a transperant header and a logo in white color.
But when i scroll down my logo isn't visible because of white body color. I want to add black logo when i scroll down. How to do it ?

This is my code. :

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
if ($(this).scrollTop()) {
    $('.navbar').addClass("shrink");
    //$('.navbar-brand  img').attr('src', 'images/logo.png');
}else{
    $('.navbar').removeClass("shrink");
    //$('.navbar-brand  img').attr('src', 'images/logo.png');
}
});
```

but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add scroll amount. Replace your code with this one.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 70) { // Set position from top
    $('.navbar').addClass("shrink");
    //$('.navbar-brand  img').attr('src', 'images/logo.png');
}else{
    $('.navbar').removeClass("shrink");
    //$('.navbar-brand  img').attr('src', 'images/logo.png');
}
});
```

Hope It works. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks Bro Its working. :) and don't forget to remove the comment lines

Comment: My Pleasure :) @DipankarDas

Comment: There is a problem with this solution. `scroll` event is fired with every scroll movement in the page. If you move from `scrollTop = 90` to `scrollTop = 120`, your condition will be met and the code for img replacement will run, even though it should not run, because the logo has already been changed. You need to add some control to detect changes only if the value goes from < 70 to > 70, or the other way aorund.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop()>70) {
        $('#header img').attr('src','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/600px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png');
    }
    else {
        $('#header img').attr('src','https://www.seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/apple-logo-eps-logo-vector-400x400.png');
    }
})
```

```css
body {
    height: 1500px;
}

#header {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}  

#header img {
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
 <img src="https://www.seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/apple-logo-eps-logo-vector-400x400.png">   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this, it will help you.

```js
$(function() { var logo = $(".lrg-logo"); $(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {
      if(!logo.hasClass("sml-logo")) {
        logo.hide();
        logo.removeClass('lrg-logo').addClass("sml-logo").fadeIn( "slow");
      }
    } else {
      if(!logo.hasClass("lrg-logo")) {
        logo.hide();
        logo.removeClass("sml-logo").addClass('lrg-logo').fadeIn( "slow");
      }
    }

});
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 2000px;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
}

.lrg-logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}

.sml-logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<header>
  <div class="lrg-logo">Logo</div>
</header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`scrollTop` will return a value while this line `if ($(this).scrollTop())` will look for a boolean value.

So test the value in the loop condition

```
if ($(this).scrollTop()===someNumber) {
//rest of code
}
```

Comment: What if `$(this).scrollTop()` never gets the value `someNumber`? When scrolling with a mouseWheel the value of `scrollTop` will jump by roughly 25 units, so the condition might never be met, even if the user has actually scrolled below the point where OP wants the logo changed.